# Run multiple Python scripts simultaneously from PHP

Tags: php, python, bash, scripting

I know if I want to run multiple Python scripts simultaneously I can knock up a bash file that looks like this;

```
#!/bin/bash
python pr1.py & 
python pr2.py &
python now.py &
python loader.py &
```

But what if I want to do the same thing directly from PHP?  It seems clunky to call a bash script from PHP which then runs the Python scripts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php execute a background process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052162/run-bash-command-from-php & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155669/call-python-script-from-bash-with-argument

Comment: Have you found an answer to that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as that goes, it seems clunky to call a Python script from PHP, but you could try the [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) function or [execution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php).

Comment: Sure but how can I use shell_exec() to call multiple scripts simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `proc_open` to run multiple Python scripts simultaneously using PHP. This provides more control over the process, and we can handle them independently.

```php
<?php

$pythonScriptPathOne = 'script1.py';
$pythonScriptPathTwo = 'script2.py';

$command1 = "python $pythonScriptPathOne";
$command2 = "python $pythonScriptPathTwo";

$descriptors = [
    0 => ['pipe', 'r'], // stdin
    1 => ['pipe', 'w'], // stdout
    2 => ['pipe', 'w'], // stderr
];

// Start the first Python script
$process1 = proc_open($command1, $descriptors, $pipes1);
if (is_resource($process1)) {
    fclose($pipes1[0]);

    // Start the second Python script
    $process2 = proc_open($command2, $descriptors, $pipes2);
    if (is_resource($process2)) {
        fclose($pipes2[0]);

        $output1 = stream_get_contents($pipes1[1]);
        fclose($pipes1[1]);
        proc_close($process1);

        $output2 = stream_get_contents($pipes2[1]);
        fclose($pipes2[1]);
        proc_close($process2);

        // Display the output
        echo "Output from script1: $output1\n";
        echo "Output from script2: $output2\n";
    }
}

?>

?>
```

Insert as many `if` as you want according to number of python programs. This works fine for me !