# Using a bash script to execute python script with arguments

Tags: python, bash

I have been searching for an answer to no avail.  I have a python script that I would like to run that has quite a few arguments.  It works just fine when I run the command from the terminal, but as soon as I try to put it in a bash script it no longer works.

```
script.py --arg1 --arg2 --arg3 --arg4 --arg5
```

This works.

```
#!/bin/bash
script.py --arg1 --arg2 --arg3 --arg4 --arg5
```

This does not.  I get no error message or output.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "doesn't work".  Do you get any output?  How are you running your script?

Comment: What is the error message when you ran the bash script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call Python script from bash with argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155669/call-python-script-from-bash-with-argument)

Comment: Which shell is your terminal running?  What is the error message?

Comment: What I meant by doesn't work is I get no output or error message.  If I append an echo 'Done' to the bash script, I never see the Done output.

Comment: How are you actually running the script?

Comment: I've done chmod +x on the script and am running it using ./bashscript.sh

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your Bash script as such. Something in your Python script is behaving differently when it is being invoked noninteractively.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
python script.py --arg1 --arg2 --arg3 --arg4 --arg5
```

The above assumes python executable is present in your path. If it is not you could also use the full path to python as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/python script.py --arg1 --arg2 --arg3 --arg4 --arg5
```

Comment: Why would this be necessary in the script, but not when he runs it by hand?

Comment: I have tried adding the path to python as well as the full path to the script.  I still see no output or error messages when executing the bash script.