# How to pass a variable to all processes ran by pool.map?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm relatively new to Python3 and am starting to dabble in multiprocessing.  I have searched for answers regarding my question, and have seen the [starmap solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5442981/6711085), but I'm not sure if it will work for me.

My projects consists of several `.py` files. Each one connects to a device and gathers stats, builds an HTML table, and updates my website with the latest data.  In order to launch/control these processes, I have a file `main.py` that handles the multiprocessing:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import time

processes = ('1.py', '2.py', '3.py', '4.py')

def run_process(process):
    os.system('sudo python3 {}'.format(process)) 

pool = Pool(processes=4)

while True:
    pool.map(run_process, processes)
    time.sleep(60)
```

Note: I'm using sudo so that python can read a password from a root-owned file that is used for SSH connections in each of the processes. Also note: each of my "processes" files (ie: `1.py`) can be ran independently of `main.py`, and in no way needs to communicate back to `main.py` or with any of the other processes.

My question is: how can I pass a variable to each of the processes?  I want each process to know how many times it has ran so I can run a specific function once every X number of times.

I have no idea how to accomplish this, and this is actually the first time I am completely stuck since I began learning Python about 4 months ago.  I can't simply place a counter in each of the `#.py` files because of how I am executing them (as in, they run, and they terminate completely when they're done - in other words, from the perspective of `#.py`, every time it runs, it is the first time running). The below code may not be valid python code, but I imagine it would look something like this (in an effort to illustrate what I want to do):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import time

processes = ('1.py', '2.py', '3.py', '4.py')

def run_process(process):
    os.system('sudo python3 {}'.format(process)) 

pool = Pool(processes=4)
run_counter = 0
while True:
    pool.map(run_process, processes, run_counter)
    time.sleep(60)
    run_counter += 1
```

To further demonstrate my point, for example, `1.py` would accept the run_counter variable and have some logic that says "if this is the first time I'm running, do foo(); otherwise, skip it" - if this is the 10th/20th/30th/etc time I'm running, do foo().  This is an effort to further optimize my program because it's doing a lot of excess work that isn't absolutely necessary with each iteration.

Thanks!

## Update 1:

I've been playing around with passing a global variable to try to get it to work, but I'm running into an issue with this possible solution. My code example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import time

processes = ('1.py', '2.py', '3.py', '4.py')
run_counter = 1

def run_process(process):
    global run_counter
    os.system('sudo python3 {0} {1}'.format(process, run_counter))

pool = Pool(processes=4)

while True:
    pool.map(run_process, processes)
    time.sleep(60)
    run_counter += 1
    print("Updating run counter to {}".format(run_counter))
```

And in my file `1.py` I have the following:

```
import sys
run_counter = sys.argv[1]
print("Run counter from 1.py is {}".format(run_counter))
```

When I execute main.py, I see the following:

`Run counter from 1.py is 1
Updating run counter to 2
Run counter from 1.py is 1
Updating run counter to 3
Run counter from 1.py is 1`

I'm aware that changing a global variable requires the `global myVar` statement before the change and I've tried that too - both ways produce the same output.

Comment: I have not tried that because I am assuming that a global variable is not accessible between each python3 process on the host. What I mean is, I launch main.py with `sudo python3 main.py` and then main.py launches each #.py file with `sudo python3 1.py`, so there are actually 5 python processes running at once on my host machine. Honestly I haven't used global variables in Python yet, but my understanding of them is that they are for sharing inside/outside of functions within the same process.

Comment: I do see what you're saying Carcigenicate, but I'm not sure if I can pass a variable in on the call, like: `os.system('sudo python3 {0} {1}'.format(process, run_counter))`. I have no idea if that is valid python, nor would I know how to "accept" the variable in the python file itself.

Edit: [Well that was an easy search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155669/call-python-script-from-bash-with-argument).