# How to pass arguments to python script?

Tags: python, shell

I've got a python script for automating a task. But every time I run it, it asks for input to provide. So for instance when I run the following command:

```
$ python icecream.py
Which flavor do you want to choose?
1. Blueberry
2. Vanilla
```

What I want to know is that how can I provide pre-input to the script if I like the vanilla flavor. Can I use a flag like `python icecream.py -1`. I'm a beginner at this, so please tolerate if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: shot answer: [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: Interesting setup you got there. If you use it for automation it might be more useful to remove the input from your function and directly call the script using an argument from shell. They explain it well here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155669/call-python-script-from-bash-with-argument

Comment: this depends on your OS, of course, but in Unixy bash-like shells, pipe the input `printf "1\n" | python icecream.py` but it's probably better to create the script to accept arguments, not using `input()`

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. It did the trick for me.